# Input validation in Vuetify 3 without using a form

Tags: vuejs3, vuetify.js

I have the validation working but I don't know how to check if all fields are valid since I'm not using a form tag.

My fields post to an api and doesn't need an actual form.

Is there a way to use a form tag without submitting so I don't have to have a page refresh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, you use v-form in Vuetify and prevent the page reload in the event handler:

```html
<v-form @submit.prevent="handleSubmit">
  <v-text-field
    ...
  />
</v-form>
```

The event passed to the handler implements a Promise interface, that lets you await the validation result:

```
async function handleSubmit(submitEventPromise) {
  const {valid, errors} = await submitEventPromise
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. ty!